# How to compute the duration between two chrono::DateTime?

Tags: rust, rust-chrono

I am using the [chrono](https://crates.io/crates/chrono) crate and want to compute the `Duration` between two `DateTime`s.

```rust
use chrono::Utc;
use chrono::offset::TimeZone;

let start_of_period = Utc.ymd(2020, 1, 1).and_hms(0, 0, 0);
let end_of_period = Utc.ymd(2021, 1, 1).and_hms(0, 0, 0);

// What should I enter here?
//
// The goal is to find a duration so that
// start_of_period + duration == end_of_period
// I expect duration to be of type std::time
let duration = ... 

let nb_of_days = duration.num_days();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`DateTime` implements `Sub<DateTime>`, so you can just subtract the most recent date from the first one:

```
let duration = end_of_period - start_of_period;
println!("num days = {}", duration.num_days());
```

Answer (score 4):

Seeing the docs of Utc: https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.11/chrono/offset/struct.Utc.html

By calling either the method `.now` (or `.today`) you get back a struct that implements [`Sub<Date<Tz>> for Date<Tz>`](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.11/chrono/struct.Date.html#impl-Sub%3CDate%3CTz%3E%3E), from source you can see it is returning an `OldDuration`, which is just a type alias around [`Duration`](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.11/chrono/struct.Duration.html).

Finally, you can use the `Duration` with the other types implementing `Add` for it, like [`DateTime`](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.11/chrono/struct.DateTime.html#impl-Add%3CDuration%3E).

So the code should look like this:

```rust
let start_of_period = Utc.ymd(2020, 1, 1).and_hms(0, 0, 0);
let end_of_period = Utc.ymd(2021, 1, 1).and_hms(0, 0, 0);

let duration = end_of_period.now() - start_of_period.now();
```