# How to subtract two Chrono DateTime objects to obtain the Duration difference between them, when the DateTime types differ?

Tags: datetime, rust, timezone, rust-chrono

I have two `DateTime` objects *of different type* which I would like to be able to subtract, or otherwise find the `Duration` difference between.

Here is some example code:

```
// First step: Want to be able to construct DateTimes for a set of different
// timezones.
//
// To do this, we first create a Utc now object, and convert it to different
// timezones, as required. For example here, we convert to London.
let utc_now = Utc::now();
let naive_utc_datetime = utc_now.naive_local();
    // Since this time is in Utc, `naive_local` should return the same as
    // `naive_utc` ?

// Create London time from a chrono_tz Timezone
let london_now = chrono_tz::Europe::London.from_utc_datetime(&naive_utc_datetime);
println!("london_now: {}", london_now);
    // london_now: 2023-08-31 10:07:43.421198168 BST

let difference_from_utc = london_now - utc_now;
println!("difference_from_utc: {}", difference_from_utc);
    // does not compile
```

The final line does not compile, this is why:

```
cannot subtract `DateTime<Utc>` from `DateTime<Tz>`
the trait `Sub<DateTime<Utc>>` is not implemented for `DateTime<Tz>`
the following other types implement trait `Sub<Rhs>`:
  <DateTime<Tz> as Sub<Days>>
  <DateTime<Tz> as Sub<FixedOffset>>
  <DateTime<Tz> as Sub<Months>>
  <DateTime<Tz> as Sub<chrono::Duration>>
  <DateTime<Tz> as Sub>
```

The question is, how can we obtain the `Duration` (or otherwise) difference between the time in London and the Utc time. Since it is currently British Summer Time, I would expect to see a difference of exactly 1 hour on todays date. (2023-08-31)

---

Related: The following question explains how to subtract two `DateTime::<T>` objects assuming they have the same type `T`.

This will work if both datetimes are `DateTime::<Utc>` but not otherwise.

- [How to compute the duration between two chrono::DateTime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61040911/how-to-compute-the-duration-between-two-chronodatetime)

Comment: "*the trait `Sub<DateTime<Utc>>` is not implemented for `DateTime<Tz>`*" - ignoring the technical details, this does not make much sense to me from a theoretical perspective. UTC is not a time zone, however, durations between UTC datetime and timezone-aware datetime should be unambiguous, assuming the appropriate time zone rules are applied.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the datetimes to [`NaiveDateTime`](https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/naive/struct.NaiveDateTime.html):

```rust
let difference_from_utc = london_now.naive_local() - utc_now.naive_local();
```

For UTC, it is faster to use [`naive_utc()`](https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/struct.DateTime.html#method.naive_utc):

```rust
let difference_from_utc = london_now.naive_local() - utc_now.naive_utc();
```

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant I didn't ask for your upvote. I posted it here for you and for posterity. And for the record, I was not the downvoter in this case, and [you should not assume you know who is the downvoter](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388686/why-shouldnt-i-assume-i-know-who-downvoted-my-post).

Comment: I do not think the answer is good, because it required converting to naive forms.

Comment: I don't think this is a problem, especially given that we calculate-and-throw-away it, but of course you're free to think otherwise. Nevertheless, it's still better than your answer, that converts the `DateTime` to a type it clearly _is not_.

Comment: I would **guess** although I don't know if this is the case, that it **might** be possible to convert a `DateTime<Utc>` to `DateTime<FixedOffset>` which **maybe** could be subtracted from `london_now`. I would suggest this is the "real" solution but I have not yet figured out how to do that. I agree, converting to `Utc` is not **ideal** but it is better than throwing away the timezone information.

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant This won't help; as you've noticed in your answer, subtracting `DateTime` ignores the time zone and only compares the UTC time.

Comment: Fair enough. This is a good point.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to convert the current London Datetime, which is some kind of `DateTime<FixedOffset>` type into a `DateTime<Utc>` object.

```
println!("london_now.naive_local(): {}", london_now.naive_local());
    // 2023-08-31 10:07:43.421198168

// force it into a type which can be subtracted
// this is perhaps a misnomer, because this time IS NOT a utc time
let london_now_utc = Utc.from_local_datetime(&london_now.naive_local()).unwrap();

let difference_from_utc = london_now_utc - utc_now;
println!("difference_from_utc: {}", difference_from_utc); // PT3600S
```

However, this example only works for subtracting two Utc times. If we wanted to subtract two `DateTime` objects for a London and Chicago time, this method would suggest both have to be converted to UTC first, which seems inefficient.

---

I thought it may be possible to subtract two `DateTime<FixedOffset>` types, but this does not produce the expected result.

For example:

```
let london_now = chrono_tz::Europe::London.from_utc_datetime(&naive_utc_datetime);
println!("london_now: {}", london_now);
    // london_now: 2023-08-31 10:21:36.642965010 BST

let chicago_now = chrono_tz::America::Chicago.from_utc_datetime(&naive_utc_datetime);
println!("chicago_now: {}", chicago_now);
    // chicago_now: 2023-08-31 04:21:36.642965010 CDT

println!("difference Chicago - London: {}", chicago_now - london_now);
```

I can sort of imagine why the difference is zero. Both "times" are in different "timezones". When we compute the difference between them we find that although the displayed time is very different, the difference in time is still zero.